# Separar por celdas información de la tabla SQL en CSV

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Tengo la siguiente función que me descarga en formato CSV la información de una tabla, pero al revisar el archivo toda la información sale una celda.

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM add_courier ORDER BY id DESC");

    if($query->num_rows > 0){
        $delimiter = ",";
        $filename = "Solicitudes_" . date('Y-m-d') . ".csv";
        
        $f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');
        
        $fields = array('ID', 'Quid', 'Email', 'Documento', 'Nombre', 'Email');
        fputcsv($f, $fields, $delimiter);
        
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
            $status = ($row['status_courier'] == 'Delivered');
            $lineData = array($row['id'], $row['quid'], $row['tracking'], $row['r_address'], $row['r_phone'], $status);
            fputcsv($f, $lineData, $delimiter);
        }
        
        fseek($f, 0);
        
        header('Content-Type: text/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');
        
        fpassthru($f);
    }
    exit;
```

a que se debera?

Dejo captura de como sale el archivo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estás creando un archivo separado por coma. Si por ejemplo quieres verlo en celdas diferentes en Excel u otro programa tienes que indicar al momento de cargar que es un CSV.

Comment: pues en los header ya se especifica que es un csv

Comment: Ya, pero si lo intentas abrir en Excel debes indicar la opción desde un CSV o algo así.

Comment: si, era eso, yo creí que era mas por el code, muchas Gracias